# Custom drawn object won't respond to touch event

Tags: android, canvas, android-drawable

I'm creating a custom seek bar which allows the user to drag a circle inside of a ring. I have completed both the circle and ring using canvas classes. You can see the image of this below.

[image]

To match the location of the circle within the ring (0 deg=0%, 90 deg=25%, 180 deg=50% etc...), I plan on using trigonometric inversion (arcTan) and displaying that percentage in the center of the circle.

I am attempting to allow the user to drag the circle inside the ring via user touch by fixing the blue line at the center of the circle, then making the circle a touch event small blue circle is to be swung around by the fixed blue line). I plan on eventually setting the blue line to transparent to make the blue circle seem fixed inside the blue ring. My problem is, the touch event for the blue circle is not responding at all (to be dragged inside blue ring). Any suggestions to make this happen?

```
public class barSeeker extends View {

    private Paint kCirclePaint; //Set ring color
    Paint mPaint=new Paint(); //To make various colors
    float startX; // to position line inside ring
    float startY; // to position line ring
    float stopX; // to position line ring
    float stopY; // to position line  ring
    float mX; //Center of big yellow ring x-coordinate
    float mY; //Center of big yellow ring y-coordinate
    float mX2; //Center of blue ring x-coordinate
    float mY2; //Center of blue ring y- coordinate
    int radius = 250; //Large yellow ring to create highlite effect behind blue ring
    int radius2 = 250; // Big blue ring
    float radius_small=50; //Radius of small blue circle


    public barSeeker(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public barSeeker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        Init(attrs);
    }

    public barSeeker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        Init(attrs);
    }

    public barSeeker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        Init(attrs);

    }

    private void Init(AttributeSet set){

    if(set==null)
        return;

        kCirclePaint = new Paint();
        kCirclePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        kCirclePaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#88bbff")); //YEllow Ring color
        Paint mPaint=new Paint();
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(50);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE); //Blue ring color
    }

        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(100);
            // Setting the color of the circle
            mPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            mX=getWidth()/2; //Coordinates for big circle x-axis
            mY=getHeight()/2; // Coordinates for big circle y-axis

            mPaint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);              // Second yellow big circle to create highlite effect on big blue circle
            mPaint.setDither(true);                    // set the dither to true
            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);       // set to STOKE
            mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);    // set the join to round you want
            mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);      // set the paint cap to round too
            mPaint.setPathEffect(new CornerPathEffect(50) );   // set the path effect when they join.
            mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

            RectF oval = new RectF(mX - radius, mY - radius, mX + radius, mY + radius); //Draw big circle background yellow
            canvas.drawArc(oval, -70, 320, false, mPaint);
            mX2=getWidth()/2; // Center for Big Circle
            mY2=getHeight()/2; //Center for Big Circle
            mPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(80);
            mPaint.setDither(true);                    // set the dither to true
            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);       // set to STOKE
            mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);    // set the join to round you want
            mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
            RectF oval2 = new RectF(mX2 - radius2, mY2 - radius2, mX2 + radius2, mY2 + radius2); //Big Blue Ring
            canvas.drawArc(oval2, -70, 320, false, mPaint); //Big Blue Ring


            mPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
            mPaint.setDither(true);

            startX=mX2; //Coordinates for line start x-axis
            startY=mY2; //Coordinates for line start y-axis
            stopX=mX2; //Coordinates for line end x-axis
            stopY=mY2 - radius2; //Coordinates for line end y-axis

            canvas.drawLine(startX, startY, stopX, stopY, mPaint); // line attached to circle
            canvas.drawCircle(stopX, stopY,radius_small, mPaint);// circle inside barseeker
            canvas.rotate(360,startX, startY ); //Lock the line in place at center of circle so small circle can be dragged inside ring
            invalidate();

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            boolean value= super.onTouchEvent(event);

            if(event.getAction()==event.ACTION_MOVE){
                float x=event.getX();
                float y=event.getY();
                    int endAngle=updateRotation(stopX, stopY);

                    double endAngleRadian = endAngle * (Math.PI / 180);

                    int pointX = (int) Math.round((startX + radius2 * Math.cos(endAngleRadian)));
                    int pointY = (int) Math.round((startY + radius2 * Math.sin(endAngleRadian)));
                    stopX = pointX;
                    stopY = pointX;

                double dx=Math.pow(x - stopX,2);
                double dy=Math.pow(y - stopY,2);

                if(dx + dy<Math.pow(radius_small, 2)){ // if this is true, you are touching small circle
                    stopX=x;
                    stopX=y;
                    postInvalidate();
                    return true;
                }
                return value;
            }
            return true;
        }

private int updateRotation(float x, float y){
    double r=Math.atan2(x-stopX, y-stopY); //find angle of small circle
    rotation=(int)Math.toDegrees(r); convert to degrees
    return rotation;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To the solution is to set up a class which captures the angle from the radius of the circle relative to the x-axis.

```
public int updateRotation(float x, float y) {
    r = Math.atan2(x - startX, y - startY);
    rotation = -(int) Math.toDegrees(r)+70;
    //radiusConverter.setPercent(rotation);
    //notifyAll();
    return rotation;
}
```

Then in a Motion Event switch case, recovering that angle and reporting it as a new x,y point.

```
    endAngle = Float.valueOf(updateRotation(x, y));

    endAngleRadian = endAngle *((float)Math.PI / 180);
rotationUpdate.setRotation(endAngleRadian);

    pointX = (int) Math.round((startX + radius2 * Math.cos(endAngleRadian)));
    pointY = (int) Math.round((startY + radius2 * Math.sin(endAngleRadian)));
```